# Problems with jquery ajax search form div display

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, forms

I am building a search form that has a drop down menu. When you select an item in the drop down menu it calls another php file using ajax and it returns tags to resize the drop down list and the search text box field. Another jquery ajax does a call using input event to show search results items in another DIV list that displays under the search txt box. This all works fine when you use either one, but they both only work the first time. If you select an item in the drop down list it resizes but then the search txt drop down and the drop down list resize doesn't work ever again unless you refresh the browser. If you type in search txt it executes fine and displays the drop down div tag under the txt box. The search txt input using keypress works every time but everything quits working when I call to resize the drop down list. Ive tried many different things and nothing works to fix this issue. I am new to jquery so any help is appreciated. One block of code calls to resize the drop down list, one block calls to change the search txt div tag results if a different item is selected in the drop down list, and the other block of code refreshes the div tag results for each keypress in the search txt box. Ive tried document.ready and many other things but nothing seems to work.

[Here is a link to the test search form](http://www.zotchy.com/test.php?user=help)

```js
//Code block #1 resizes the drop down list and search txt box when new //item is selected in the drop down list

$('#TESTsearchtxtboxdepartmentslist').on('input', function () {


    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to ajax.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "../test/TESTajx.php?class=classTESTTopBar&func=funcTESTCreateSearchDeptList&wif=1&depID=" + $("#TESTsearchtxtboxdeplist").val(),
        dataType: "html", 
        success: function (response) {
            $("#TESTidsearchproductsform").html(response); 


        }


    });


});



//Code block #2 changes search results in DIV tag when a different item //is selected in the drop down list


    $('#TESTsearchtxtboxdepartmentslist').on('change', function () {


          $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to ajax.php
              type: "GET",
              url: "../test/TESTajx.php?class=classTESTTopBar&func=funcTESTSearchTxtInput&SearchTxtString=" + $("#TESTsearchtxtbox").val() + "&sdepID=" + $("#TESTsearchtxtboxdeptlist").val(),
              dataType: "html",
              success: function (response) {


                  if (response.trim() == '') {

                      $("#TESTsearchtxtboxlistcontent").hide();

                  } else {

                      $("#TESTsearchtxtboxlistcontent").html(response); 

                      $("#TESTsearchtxtboxlistcontent").show();
                  }

              }

          });

    });


//Code block #3 displays DIV tag under the search txt box every time a //new key is entered or removed

    $('#TESTsearchtxtbox').on('input', function () {


        $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to ajax.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "../test/TESTajx.php?class=classTESTTopBar&func=funcTESTSearchTxtInput&TESTSearchTxtString=" + $(this).val() + "&DEPID=" + $("#TESTsearchtxtboxdeptlist").val(),
            dataType: "html", 
            success: function (response) {


                if (response.trim() == '') {

                    $("#TESTsearchtxtboxlistcontent").hide(); 


                } else {

                    $("#TESTsearchtxtboxlistcontent").html(response);

                    $("#TESTsearchtxtboxlistcontent").show();
                }


            }

        });

    });
```

][1](http://www.zotchy.com/test.php?user=help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely to be because you replace the html content with the response from the ajax call. So looking at the dropdown, for example, you set an "input" event on '#TESTsearchtxtboxdepartmentslist'. Once that event is triggered your code replaces all html inside '#TESTidsearchproductsform' which includes the dropdown itself. So effectively you now have a *new* dropdown on the page with no events attached.

You want to look into event delegation with jQuery: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

With that you could do something like:

```
$("#TESTidsearchproductsform").on('input', '#TESTsearchtxtboxdepartmentslist', function(){
...
});
```

That way the event remains attached to '#TESTidsearchproductsform' and will apply to any new '#TESTsearchtxtboxdepartmentslist' that may be created on the page.

---

UPDATE FOLLOWING COMMENTS

There are many other way of coding this so I am answering based on the code you already have and from what I can understand:

1. Leave the code starting `$("#TESTidsearchproductsform").on('input', '#TESTsearchtxtboxdepartmentslist', function () {` as you have it, that's fine
2. Change the code starting `$('#TESTsearchtxtboxdepartmentslist').on('change', function () {` so it is delegated to the form i.e. `$("#TESTidsearchproductsform").on('change', '#TESTsearchtxtboxdepartmentslist', function () {`
3. Change the code starting `$('#TESTsearchtxtbox').on('input', function () {` so it is also delegated to the form i.e. `$("#TESTidsearchproductsform").on('input', '#TESTsearchtxtbox', function () {`
4. Move the div#TESTsearchtxtboxlistcontent so that it is outside of the form tag in the original html so that it is not overwritten by the ajax result

Comment: Thanks a lot for that information. It makes sense what you are saying. I changed it using your example and it made my drop down list work perfectly but my search txt input field will still not display the div drop down search results. I tried a couple different things and still cant get that portion to work. Im gonna look at it in more detail but I might have to change the way my php is returning the html tags. Php is returning the drop down list, the search txt box and the search results list items but not the DIV tag where the search results are displayed.

Comment: It shouldn't need to return the DIV. I've just looked at the code and your '#TESTsearchtxtbox' is still getting the input event attached directly instead of delegated the same way like your dropdown. If that is being replaced by the html then you have to delegate that event as well.

Comment: By the way, if your search results DIV is being replaced by the returned html then move it outside the form. Your CSS positions it absolutely so it shouldn't really matter where it is on the page. That way the ajax doesn't need to return it each time.

Comment: All of the response comes back in one ajax call. I tried doing it like this...$("#TESTidsearchproductsform").on('input', '#TESTsearchtxtboxdepartmentslist', '#TESTsearchtxtbox', function (). My question is how do I code it so it comes back as TESTsearchtxtboxdepartmentslist and TESTsearchtxtbox?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Each of your events does something different, it seems, so I do not think combining them like you have suggested in you comment will work. Hopefully my updated answer will help. By the way, the 2nd parameter to delegated events is a normal jQuery selector, so if you understand jQuery selectors you will understand why what you tried didn't do what you expected. Parameter 3 must be the callback function. Anyway, see my updated answer and let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That did fix it. At first I did it to the first and third one but didn't do the 2nd one. After doing the event delegation to all three it works perfectly.

Comment: That's great. I would appreciate if you could accept my answer then please. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer